# Sending two parameters in Html.ActionLink

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I want to use Html.ActionLink to generate link in my mvc jquery mobile website. I want to pass two parameters, style and data-theme set to b. Somewhere I read that data-theme should be sent as data_theme in order to work with this helper and this works fine when data_theme is only parameter in ActionLink. Now I want to add second parameter and I tried with

```
@Html.ActionLink("TestLink", "Index", "Home", new { data_theme = "b" }, new { style = "padding-top:15px; height:25px;" })
```

but when I look generated link inside source it's

```
<a class="ui-link ui-btn" style="padding-top:15px; height:25px;" href="/?data_theme=b">TestLink</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, both `data_theme` and `style` are `htmlattributes`.

So you should use this [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), 
and use it like

```
@Html.ActionLink("TestLink", "Index", "Home", null, new { data_theme = "b", style= "padding-top:15px; height:25px;" })
```

see the null  as fourth (or fifth as it's an extension method) parameter, which represents the routeValues, which you don't need.